# Dynamic Column Selection SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, dynamic-programming

I have the following table's in my SQL database.

```
DIM_BENCHMARK:
Fund_sk | Num_Bench | Bench | Weight | Type_Return
   1          2        XXX      0.9        TR
   1          2        YYY      0.1        Net
   2          3        XXX      0.45       TR
   2          3        YYY      0.45       TR
   2          3        ZZZ      0.10       Net

FACT_Returns:
 Date   | Bench |  TR   |   Net  
 10/10    XXX    0.010    0.005 
 10/10    YYY    0.012    0.008
 10/10    ZZZ    0.006    0.012
```

Desired Output of Stored Procedure:

```
FACT_Result:
 Date   | Fund_SK | Num_Bench |      Bench_Returns
 10/10     1           2         (eg. 0.9*TR of XXX) + (0.1*Net Return of YYY) 
 10/10     2           3         (eg. 0.45*TR of XXX) + (0.45*TR of YYY) + (0.10*Net of ZZZ)
```

The tables above show the format of my input data and my desired output. I am still reasonably new to SQL and this dynamic SQL query is past the depths of my knowledge.

I would like to multiply the figures (either) FACT_Returns.TR or .Net by DIM_Benchmark.weight depending on the specification in DIM_Benchmark.Type_Return. The variables in DIM_Benchmark.Type_Return are the same as the column headers in FACT_Returns.

As always, any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Very likely that there will be multiple rows with the same Fund_sk and num_bench but the bench column will be unique for each fund_sk.

Comment: Your Tables are DIM and FACT implying this is a star schema but it is not. You need to know that this datawarehouse has not been designed properly as you should never have a n:n join between a fact and dimension.

Comment: Based on your comment I got access to the ETL and was able to change the format of the table myself. Thanks so much for your comment. I was being driven crazy...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main problem is your fact table. It is not normalised properly - you should have one row for each value.

The `unpivot` in the below SQL normalises the data.

```
select
    [date], fund_sk,Num_Bench, sum(weight * val)    
from 
(
    select * 
    from fact_returns   
    unpivot (val for type in (tr, net)) u 
) f
    inner join dim_benchmark b
        on f.bench = b.Bench
        and f.type = b.Type_Return
group by [date], fund_sk, Num_Bench
```

Comment: Thanks. Based on your suggestion to unpivot the table I got access to the ETL and I was able to format the table at source.

Answer (score 2):

This should solve the issue and would also work in any DBMS:

```
SELECT fr.date, db.fund_sk, db.num_bench, sum(db.weight *
  CASE db.type_return
    WHEN 'TR' THEN fr.tr
    WHEN 'Net' THEN fr.net
    ELSE 0
  END) Bench_Returns
FROM dim_benchmark db
JOIN fact_returns fr ON db.bench = fr.bench
GROUP BY fr.date, db.fund_sk, db.num_bench
```

Bear in mind I'm making sure only `TR` and `Net` values are considered for the `SUM`. If you only have `TR` and `Net` in that column then you can change the case to:

```
  CASE db.type_return
    WHEN 'TR' THEN fr.tr
    ELSE fr.net
  END
```

Which would run slightly faster.

Output:

```
|  DATE | FUND_SK | NUM_BENCH | BENCH_RETURNS |
|-------|---------|-----------|---------------|
| 10/10 |       1 |         2 |        0.0098 |
| 10/10 |       2 |         3 |        0.0111 |
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb6eb/1).

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using a case to calculate each row and them sum up appropriately.

```
select
     _BenchResults.date
    ,_BenchResults.Fund_SK
    ,_BenchResults.Num_Bench
    ,sum(_BenchResults.benchReturns) as benchReturns
from (
    select
         FACT_Result.date
        ,DIM_BENCHMARK.Fund_SK
        ,DIM_BENCHMARK.Num_Bench
        ,case when DIM_BENCHMARK.Type_Return = 'TR' then
            DIM_BENCHMARK.Weight * FACT_Result.tr
         when DIM_BENCHMARK.Type_Return = 'Net' then
            DIM_BENCHMARK.Weight * FACT_Result.net
         else
            0
         end as benchReturns
    from DIM_BENCHMARK
    join FACT_Result
        on FACT_Result.bench = DIM_BENCHMARK.bench
) _BenchResults
group by
     _BenchResults.date
    ,_BenchResults.Fund_SK
    ,_BenchResults.Num_Bench
```